# How to use post_id with a Class?

Tags: post-meta

I made a plugin for some calculation.

```
Class Math {
var $id; // I want to map this id to post_id
var $a;
var $b;
var $c;

function calculate{
 $this->a = $value_from_post_meta_input_box;
 $this->b = $data_generated_in_calculating_process;
 $this->c = $result_of_some_function;
}
}
```

After activating the plugin, and setting up the post meta input box for $a, I am able to get $a saved in post meta.
Now, how can I save $b and $c to post meta? How to say the current calculation is an instance of Math with current post_ID ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to save an array of values. It will be automatically serialized and unserialized.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'math', array($a, $b, $c));
```

Comment: The input box for $a is on the post-editing screen, the Math class is in a plugin. Where should I write down the update_post_meta code? if write in the Class, how it finds the $post_id? if write out of the Class, how it get the value of  $b and $c?

Comment: You should hook your save function to the [`save_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post?version=3.1&file=wp-includes/post.php) action, which takes the post ID as the first parameter.